# Drop primary key not working

Tags: mysql

I want to drop a primary key constraint from my table:

```
mysql> alter table 'carpool' drop PRIMARY KEY, add PRIMARY KEY('pool_id');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''carpool' drop PRIMARY KEY, add PRIMARY KEY('pool_id')' at line 1
```

Comment: `PRIMARY`  .... please check the doc

Comment: I have already checked the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html. But the same is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using singe quotes (') which Mysql interprets as a string and not as a column. You need to use back ticks (`), which is located to the left of the 1 on your keyboard, or just not use any at all.

```
alter table carpool drop PRIMARY KEY, add PRIMARY KEY(pool_id);

alter table `carpool` drop PRIMARY KEY, add PRIMARY KEY(`pool_id`);
```